# Custom cell not loading button background image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview

I have created a custom cell using the code below. I have only added a rounded button which is loaded correctly when `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function called, but the images are not loaded. The only thing that I can see in my tableView is circle buttons without any image in it.

Can anyone help me to find where the problem is? 
Thanks

**CustomCell.h**

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell {
    UIButton *profilePhoto;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *profilePhoto;

@end
```

**CustomCell**

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {

    [super layoutSubviews];

    profilePhoto = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    UIColor  *borderColor = [UIColor redColor];

    profilePhoto.frame = CGRectMake(5.0, 8.0, 60.0, 60.0);
    profilePhoto.clipsToBounds = YES;
    profilePhoto.layer.cornerRadius = 30;
    profilePhoto.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor;
    profilePhoto.layer.borderWidth= 1.5f;
    profilePhoto.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [self.contentView addSubview: profilePhoto];
}
```

**cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }

    // Set up the cell
    switch (indexPath.row) {

        case 0:
            [cell.profilePhoto setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nick.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            break;

        case 1:
            [cell.profilePhoto setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"michael.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            break;

        default:
            break; 
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: can you make local variables for images to ensure that is exist and loads

Comment: I have add `@syntesize profilePhoto;` and now something weird happened. The images when table loads didn't show up, but after i scroll down or up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

**CustomCell**

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
       profilePhoto = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
       UIColor  *borderColor = [UIColor redColor];
       profilePhoto.clipsToBounds = YES;
       profilePhoto.layer.cornerRadius = 30;
       profilePhoto.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor;
       profilePhoto.layer.borderWidth= 1.5f;
       profilePhoto.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
       [self.contentView addSubview: profilePhoto];
    }
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {

    [super layoutSubviews];
    profilePhoto.frame = CGRectMake(5.0, 8.0, 60.0, 60.0);
}
```

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, `profilePhoto` must be nil for first time. because cell `layoutSubviews` will be called later where you init `profilePhoto`.

And as you commented, scroll will reuse the cell which have call `layoutSubviews` then cell have `profilePhoto` object , so the image set in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` can be seen after scroll.